# A value of type "const <Component> *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "<Component> *"

Tags: c++

I have a header file in C++ with a namespace and a class in it:

```
namespace imaging
{
    class Image
    {
    protected:
        Component *buffer; // To index individual channels
        Image(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, const Component *data_ptr, bool interleaved=false); // Holds the image data
    }
}
```

When I try to implement the constructor, I get an error: `a value of type "const <Component> *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "<Component> *"`:

```
#include Image.h
namespace imaging 
{
    Image::Image(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, const Component *data_ptr, bool interleaved=false)
    {
        this->height = height;
        this->width = width;
        buffer = data_ptr; // The error is here!
    }
}
```

Comment: `data_ptr` is a pointer to `const`. `buffer` isn't. You can't assign one to the other.

Comment: Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and post the error messages verbatim here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data_ptr` is as `const Component *` while `Image::buffer` is a `Component *`

By affecting the first to the second you would discard the `const`. The whole point of this attribute is to protect data and it should be removed by a simple cast.

You could either edite you constructor argument's type to remove the `const` or use

```
buffer=const_cast<Component*>(data_ptr);
```

In any case, think about the behaviour you want. Is there any sens for the pointer to be const (it's not a ref) ?

Comment: well it is an assignment and i have orders to not change the header files and just implement them otherwise no there is no reason for me keeping it

Comment: i also want to impelemnt a method but when i try this.gettermethod() . I get an error that  'this' can used only in non static ... . its not a static method i also tried both (*this).[..]  and this->[..]  and i get the same error . You can give me your mail if you are willing to help me please. thank :)